# App replacement even after change app name and apk file name?

Tags: java, android

I start my android app writing with modifying some example codes from the internet. After some modification (Include the apk file name and the app name), I have a modified version app. When I wish to install the original example apk again, it has the message indicate that "Are you going to replace the app?" I think it want to use the original app to replace the modified version of app. What should I change so that Android won't think they are the same app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the package name in the manifest.

Comment: Just the "app name" and the "apk file name" won't do. Check the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. There should be a "`package=`" tag at the first lines. Change that value.

Comment: I see, moreover it seems should use the refactor tool to modify every file's package name in src folder. (Only modify AndroidManifest.xml won't work I think) I tried and it brings errors. Are there any rules or limitation for refactor tools?

Comment: If you right-click your project folder, there will appear a menu with an entry named *Android Tools*. There, click *Rename Application Package*. If necessary, it will provide you with a window telling all necessary changes, including the `R` imports. I don't think it has any limitation, considering this particular situation. It should take care of all that.